# Good (intro) textbook for deontic logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, deontology

I've read 90% of Sider's Logic for Philosophy and thought it was great - very lucid. Assuming I am more or less familiar with what's introduced there, are there any great resources out there for learning deontic logic? It doesn't have to be a textbook - a short paper or online lecture notes would be great too.

Comment: I think you could do worse than starting here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/

Plenty of references there to follow up with after you've read the article itself.

Comment: I found [Hansen's Is there a Logic of Imperatives?](https://archive.illc.uva.nl/ESSLLI2008/Materials/vanderTorreHansen/ESSLI_Deontic_Logic.pdf) very illuminating as an intro. His thesis [Imperatives and Deontic Logic](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4cdc/6d0c79d80c6d6314fcc0c480188cd964ad9c.pdf) is a longer version.

Comment: Edited the tags.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the [Handbook of Deontic Logic and Normative Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848901321). It provides an introduction to standard formalisms, conceptual distinctions, outstanding problems, and putative solutions, written by a variety of deontic logic specialists. I'd consider it a natural next step after working through Sider's text.